# Export mysql to txt / xml file and download it

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table which shows some mysql data, every entry has a checkbox to select individual entries, now i want to be able to export those selected entries into a xml or txt file, i tried this:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['exporttxt']) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['checkbox']); $i++) {
        $export_id = $checkbox[$i];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$export_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }


    $output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<root>\n";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $output .= "\t<row>\n";
            foreach ($myrow as $_name => $_value)
            {
                $output .= "\t\t<$_name>$_value</$_name>\n";
            }
            $output .= "\t</row>\n";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</root>";
}

header('content-type: text/xml');
header('content-disposition: attachment; filename=data_export.xml');
echo $output;
exit;

?>
```

But that didn't work at all, any hints ?

I've changed the code a bit, i am now using this

```
<?php
if ($_POST['exporttxt']) {
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
   $export_id = $checkbox[$i];
$text = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM ticket WHERE id='$export_id'");
$text = mysql_fetch_assoc($text);
$text = $text["code"];

ob_end_flush();
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.txt\"");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output).";\n");



echo($text);


}
}


?>
```

I now get proper output on my screen, but it won't offer me to download the file ?

Comment: can you echo the $export_id to make sure your getting into the loop.  Also it's not a good idea to a count in the for arguments.  Set $count = count($_POST['checkbox']) before the for loop you'll get better performance.

Comment: echoing $export_id works - partly, it is showing the id's from the checkboxes that have been selected, although only 1, why is that ? but apart from that, if i select ID 305 for example and click submit it shows "305", so that should be fine ?

Comment: can you echo  $output on the screen? ie comment out header

Comment: i commented out the headers, $output is not showing anything at all

Comment: You have no $output variable - so of course it is echoing nothing. You are trying to set headers each time you execute the `for()` loop. Messy, messy, messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code was querying each of the checkboxed IDs individually (a long and laborious way to handle it) and was trying to dump the results individually per row (not going to work well for you).

Try this. (**NOTE: Untested, but should give you a good starting point to develop.**)

```
if( $_POST['exporttxt'] ){

  if( count( $_POST['checkbox'] )>0 ){

    // If the checkbox values are meant to all be integers, you might want to perform some validation/sanitisation/filtering here
    // Up to you to do that

    // Collapse the IDs from the checkboxes into a comma-delimited string
    $export_ids = implode( ',' , $_POST['checkbox'] );

    // Template the SQL Query
    $sqlTpl = 'SELECT code FROM ticket WHERE id IN ( %s )';
    // Compile the SQL Query String
    $sqlStr = sprintf( $sqlTpl , $export_ids );

    // Execute the SQL Query
    if( !( $sqlRes = mysql_query( $sqlStr ) ) ){
      // SQL Error - Log it, Handle it
    }elseif( mysql_num_rows( $sqlRes )==0) {
      // No Rows Returned - Log it, Handle it
    }else{
      // We have results - process them
      $text = array();
      while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sqlRes ) ){
        // Looping through the returned rows, adding them to the $text array
        $text[] = $r['code'];
      }
      // Collapse the $text array down into a normal string, with one element per line
      $output = implode( "\n" , $text );

      // Output Handling from @narcisradu's answer
      header("Pragma: public");
      header("Expires: 0");
      header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      header("Cache-Control: private",false);
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary;\n");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.txt\";\n");
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Type: application/download");
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
      header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output).";\n");
      echo $output;

      die; // Prevent any further output
    }

  }else{
    // No Checkboxes Checked
    echo 'You must select one or more checkboxes to export something, muppet.';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
$export_id = $checkbox[$i];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$export_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);}
```

This piece of code will actually do a query for every element in _POST['checkbox'] array but then you are using the result of the last query and you are not parsing the result of every query.

Please make sure the generated XML is well-formed and you actually have some data, by displaying directly into the browser.

After that you may try to force download:

```
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary;\n");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".urlencode(basename($file_name))."\";\n");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output).";\n");
    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I am not getting any output at all - echoing $output, i'm using almost the same query to update values, also with checkboxes, there it works fine, i don't understand what's the problem ?

Comment: use var_dump to check your variables and see where is the mistake. For the first part of my answer: not the query is the issue, the problem is you are executing the query for every checkbox and you override the $result variable, so you will actually get only the result of the last query in the loop.

Comment: Could you please check my initial question, i've edited it with the code i am using now, this works now, also with all select boxes the only problem i have is that it is not offering me to download the file, i also tried the headers u posted, to no avail. i would also appreciate if you could tell me how i can get line breaks inbetween the output.

Comment: header("Content-type: text/plain"); - I think the browser attempts to display it here. Please check the manual page for header.